# How to add a result to array or Collection after a pipeline command?

Tags: arrays, powershell, pipeline

How can I add the output of a pipeline into an existing array?

I do something like that example:

```
$FirstCollection = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
foreach ($item in $OtherCollection) {
    if ($item -ne "blabla") {
        $result | 
        Where-Object { ($_.ID -Match 1) } |
        Group-Object -Property id, LevelDisplayName, LogName -NoElement | 
        Sort-Object -Property count -Descending |
        **This output must going into the $FirstCollection**
    }

    if ($item -ne "bliblablubb") {
        $result | 
        Where-Object { ($_.ID -Match 1) } |
        Group-Object -Property id, LevelDisplayName, LogName -NoElement | 
        Sort-Object -Property count -Descending |
        **This output must going into the $FirstCollection as well**
    }
}
```

How should I add the last output into an array? The array can also be a simple `$array = @()`.

I need this, because after the `foreach` I have to output the array entries into a file.
After the last pipe I get a Count, a value and a string and I need all outcomes line by line among themselves.

If I do output directly after the pipeline with `Out-File...` I´m getting something like this:

```
Count Name                                                               
----- ----                                                               
   69 123, someText, someMoreText
Count Name                                                               
----- ----                                                               
   50 456, someText, someMoreText
Count Name                                                               
----- ----                                                               
   25 789, someText, someMoreText
```

But I need:

```
Count Name                                                               
----- ----    
 69 123, someText, someMoreText 
 50 456, someText, someMoreText
 25 789, someText, someMoreText
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to an ArrayList in PowerShell, you do not pipe. Rather you use the `ArrayList.Add()` function or simply `+=` (just like in C#).

```
$FirstCollection = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
foreach ($item in $OtherCollection) {
    if ($item -ne "blabla") {
        $FirstCollection += $result | 
            Where-Object { ($_.ID -Match 1) } |
            Group-Object -Property id, LevelDisplayName, LogName -NoElement | 
            Sort-Object -Property count -Descending
    }

    if ($item -ne "bliblablubb") {
        $FirstCollection += $result | 
            Where-Object { ($_.ID -Match 1) } |
            Group-Object -Property id, LevelDisplayName, LogName -NoElement | 
            Sort-Object -Property count -Descending
    }
}
```

I believe this also works with `$FirstCollection = @()`.